# How to sort values of atrributes of several Java objects and sum them?

Tags: java, class, attributes

I just started to learn Java and I am stuck with one homework, which is probably very basic. It goes like this:

Write two classes, called House and Room. Room should have attributes like typeOfRoom (String) (eg. kitchen,  livingroom, bedroom ...), area (double) and floor(int). House should have rooms, made from the Room class. It also should have methods called totalArea(floor: int) and totalArea (int). The last sentence is taken literally from the assignment.

I suppose, that i have to sum values of area of all rooms with the same value of floor for the first one. For second one, I have to sum area of all rooms. The second one is not a problem for me. However, the first one is. I wrote my classes like:

```
public class House {
//Attributes
public Room bedroom;
public Room kitchen;
public Room livingroom;



//Constructor
public House (){
    bedroom = new Room();
    ...

};
//Methods
public double totalArea(){
    return bedroom.area + livingroom.area + kitchen.area;
}

public Room getBedroom() {
    return bedroom;
}

public void setBedroom(Room bedroom) {
    this.bedroom = bedroom;
}
```

etc.
}

My Room class like:

```
public class Room {
public String typeOfRoom;
public double area;
public int floor;

//Methods
public String getTypeOfRoom() {
    return typeOfRoom;
}

public void setTypeOfRoom(String typeOfRoom) {
    this.typeOfRoom = typeOfRoom;
}

public double getArea() {
    return area;
}

public void setArea(double area) {
    this.area = area;
}

public int getFloor() {
    return floor;
}

public void setFloor(int floor) {
    this.floor = floor;
}
```

}

And my Main class like

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here
    House h1 = new House();
    Room r1 = new Room();
    Room r2 = new Room();
    Room r3 = new Room();

    r1.setTypeOfRoom("bedroom");
    r1.setArea(10);
    r1.setFloor(1);

    r2.setTypeOfRoom("kitchen");
    r2.setArea(12);
    r2.setFloor(1);

    r3.setTypeOfRoom("livingroom");
    r3.setArea(15);
    r3.setFloor(2);


    h1.bedroom = r1;
    h1.kitchen = r2;
    h1.livingroom = r3;

    System.out.printf(h1.totalArea() + "\n");

}
```

}

So, how can I sum values of area attribute of all instances of the Room class, based on their value of the floor attribute?

Comment: Are you required to use hardcoded variables for the rooms (`bedroom`, `kitchen` etc.) or can you also use a collection of rooms (`List<Room> rooms`) in your  `House` class?

Comment: Probably the hardcoded variables, but I don not know it. It is not in the  assignment.

Comment: I changed the title of the question, because I accidentally copy-pasted first row of my description of the problem instead of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't use collections and values are hardcoded, I see the solution something like:

```
Map<Int, Double> floorAreas = new HashMap<>();

// Implement this method for all types of rooms, since they are hardcoded
public void setBedroom(Room bedroom) {
    double savedArea = 0;
    int currFloor = bedroom.getFloor();
    if (floorAreas.containsKey(currFloor))
        savedArea += floorAreas.get(currFloor);

    savedArea += bedroom.getArea();
    this.bedroom = bedroom;
    floorAreas.put(currFloor, savedArea);
}

public double getFloorArea(int floorNumber) {
    return floorAreas.get(floorNumber);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So the solution with collections and values would be more elegant?

Comment: @RadekJohn , you are welcome. Yes, collections are the best way to handle values of the same type. Using List<Room> to store all the rooms would allow to count floor areas much easier.